# Encrypt and decrypt data using public/private key from node

Tags: corda

Is it possible to encrypt data using the node public key to store into a state and decrypt it using the node private key? i.e. Is it possible to access the node private key?

Comment: For general purpose use of public private keys to encrypt and decrypt on Node check out this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/75880026/994876](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75880026/994876)

Answer (score 0):

The node's public and private keys are an asymmetric key pair, and are meant to be used for signing.

For encryption and decryption, you should use symmetric key cryptography.